# Using a file-based data structure instead of a database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to use a file-based data structure in ASP.NET that can be easily switched with the EntityFramework or other ORMs later?
(I want to use the typical MVC structure and not change much later)

I want to delay the decision which database to use for as long as possible while developing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with the repository structure.

The repository implementation reads the data from the files and creates the model instances.
Those can be passed to the views normally like EF-Models then.